# Very low quality flag on a closed question, can't do anything but invalidate the flag?

Tags: support, bug, flagging, 10k-tools

I got two VLQ flags in my queue... actually the question is impossible to understand by normal humans, but I can't handle the flag if I don't either, invalidate (which I will not), or add a spam/offensive flag.

What to do in such situations?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend checking to make sure you can open up the post. Maybe it's been deleted already and is just sticking around in the flag queue for a short time. If that's the case, and it disappears from the 10k tools soon, then you don't have to do anything.

If the post still exists, then this is probably a bug in the Stack Exchange system. So in that case, I recommend reporting it as a bug on [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). It will probably be handled faster there, plus it will be shown to many users from across the network who may have noticed something similar. (I recently reported [a 10k tools flagging bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215481/what-does-you-dont-have-the-permission-to-use-this-type-of-flag-mean) there, and it was quickly fixed.)

As for what to do about it in the 10k tools now, assuming you believe the very low quality flag should be actioned (or otherwise marked helpful), you can click *other* and raise a custom moderator attention flag to tell moderators what you think should be done with the post. Such flags are for situations where no other available flag adequately does the job, and this is certainly one such situation.

Finally, note that there are plenty of bad questions that should be/remain closed but where *very low quality* flags are not warranted. However, as far as I can see from this question, it really is pretty incomprehensible.

- *If* you believe the question should be deleted very soon, I'd say that you agree with the VLQ flag (and the above course of action applies).
- If you believe it would be *wrong* to delete this question more speedily than usual, then I'd say you should *dispute* the VLQ flag (by raising an "invalid flags" flag); this does not express the idea that the question should be reopened.
- If you have no opinion as to whether or not the question should be treated any different from any old "unclear what you are asking" closed question, then I recommend taking no action, and simply leaving the post in your 10k queue. It will drop out of your queue eventually, once the handling of the flag has been decided based (in part) on the input received by people who have strong enough opinions to flag.

Comment: "If you believe the question should be deleted very soon, I'd say that you agree with the VLQ flag (and the above course of action applies)." This is what I can't do in already closed questions.

Comment: @Braiam As I mentioned, until this bug is fixed, you can custom flag to express that it's VLQ and should be deleted.